# In messagepack, error while getting value from MapValue.. Please help me

Tags: java, messagepack

I'm trying to serialize map using `messagpack.write(map)`. During deserialization using `messagepack.read(byte[])` i got `MapValue`. But I cannot fetch the values using `MapValue.get(key)`. Look this problem below

```
  HashMap<Object,Object> map = new HashMap<Object, Object>();
  map.put(1,"ONE");
  map.put("ONE","TWO");
  MessagePack m= new MessagePack();
  byte[] b = m.write(map);
  MessagePack m1 = new MessagePack();
  MapValue value = (MapValue)m1.read(b);
  System.out.println(value);// here I am getting {1:"ONE",2:"TWO"}

 System.out.println( value.get(1)); // printing the value for key 1. I am getting null.
```

Please help on this.. Thanking you.

Nausadh

Comment: what is `MapValue`? show the source of `MapValue`... why `read(b)` is returning `MapValue`? and Please indent the code!!

Comment: I've never heard of `MessagePack`. Perhaps you should add some context.

Comment: What is MapValue and MessagePack?  Can you give their implementations?

Comment: They appear to be part of the [MessagePack API](http://msgpack.org/javadoc/current/overview-tree.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use ValueFactory and convert key to use a Value interface. It's not really intuitive

```
// instead of value.get(1) use following
System.out.println(value.get(ValueFactory.createIntegerValue(1)));

// if the key would be a String use:
System.out.println(value.get(ValueFactory.createRawValue("key")));
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you please add an explanation to your answer?