# Apache beam with MessagePack - how do I get values from Map<Value, Value>?

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, apache-beam, msgpack, apache-beam-io

Inside an Apache Beam transform I can successfully transform pub/sub values (in MessagePack format) that I read from Google Cloud Pub/Sub into a map of MessagePack `Value` objects like this:

```
    @ProcessElement
    public void processElement(ProcessContext c) 
    {
        Map<Value, Value> map = MessagePack.newDefaultUnpacker(c.element().getPayload()).unpackValue().asMapValue().map();
```

When I inspect `map` I can see the following:

[image]

If I then try to get a value like this it always returns null:

```
map.get("Tz")
```

How do I get a value? Do I need to transform the values in a different way, or do I need a different way of retrieving them?

Answer (score 2):

The map is Map, so the key is a value object, but you are using a String s the key when you do map.get("Tz")

Can you create a Value object using Tz and attempt to get based on that Value object?

Comment: Thanks @Justin +1 - I was thinking on these lines. I've posted the solution - I needed an additional import for `ValueFactory`.

Answer (score 2):

The map keys are MessagePack `Value` objects, so I needed to do this to reference the key, and return the values as strings:

```
import org.msgpack.value.ValueFactory;

map.get(ValueFactory.newString("Tz")).toString()
```

See also [In messagepack, error while getting value from MapValue.. Please help me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17993145/in-messagepack-error-while-getting-value-from-mapvalue-please-help-me) (the solution didn't work in my case, but there are some suggestions there for dealing with different types that can be used in a `Map`)